# Find first and second match of a list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have text cells in column and i have a list of words, i need to get the first and second match of text cell within this list of word using formula without vba.

[here is an example of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDw4c.png)

Comment: Do you mean first and second match because 'apple' comes before 'orange' in the text, or because 'apple' comes before 'orange' in the list?

Comment: Order isn't important, the point is finding a word from the LIST within the TEXT CELLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text cells start in A2, then:

```
First Match  B2:  =IFERROR(MID($A2,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(LIST,$A2),COLUMNS($A:A)),FIND(" ",$A2&" ",AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(LIST,$A2),COLUMNS($A:A)))-AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(LIST,$A2),COLUMNS($A:A))),"")
```

and fill right one cell to get the 2nd Match.  Then fill down as far as needed.

[image]

**EDIT:** The OP has added an additional requirement having to do with excluding words within words, eg do NOT find `also` if the word is `Calso`; and also do not return punctuation.

Although cumbersome in formulas, this can be handling by
 - Replacing all of the punctuation with `space`
 - Adding a space at the beginning and end of the sentence
 - Adding a space at the beginning and end of each word in `LIST`
 - adjusting the formula to not return the extra space.

The above can be done most simply by modifying the defined name `LIST` and also by using a defined name for a formula to do the punctuation replacement and space prefix and suffix.

Given the example above, we redefine `LIST`

```
LIST refers to: =" " & Sheet1!$F$2:$F$6 & " "
```

and, with some cell in **Row 2** selected, we define `theSentence`

```
theSentence refers to:  =" " & TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!$A10,","," "),"'"," "),"."," "),"!"," "))& " "
```

That particular definition will remove comma, apostrophe, period and exclamation point.  If you need to remove other punctuation, you can just nest more `SUBSTITUTE`'s

And we make some changes in the formula in B2:

```
B2: =IFERROR(MID(theSentence,1+AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(LIST,theSentence),COLUMNS($A:A)),FIND(" ",theSentence,1+AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(LIST,theSentence),COLUMNS($A:A)))-AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(LIST,theSentence),COLUMNS($A:A))-1),"")
```

Comment: Very nice (assuming first interpretation of the question I asked OP but which hasn't got an answer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very good but with two problems, the first one, that it will return a result of any word contains one of the LIST words. so if there is a word like "Calso" it will be returned in the First or Second match cells because it contains "also", moreover, if there was "apple, and orange" it will return "apple," with the comma in the first match. this will cause a lot of problems and miss-matching in the results. i'll appreciate if there is a way to solve these points.

Comment: @user3503064 That is different from your original data.  And it is probably solvable by using nested `SUBSTITUTES` to remove the punctuation, and then ensuring that your search terms include `space` before and after each word.  Feel free to modify the formula.  Personally, I would use VBA and regular expressions for problems of that complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i added the spaces and it was great, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is the second interpretation of the question (find the first and second match in the list of a string anywhere in the text).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$6,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&$F$2:$F$6&" "," "&$A2&" ")),ROW($F$2:$F$6)-ROW($F$1)),COLUMNS($A1:A1))),"")
```

Note that this is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I have put spaces in after reading OP's comment although it would have been better if the question had been posed more clearly in the first place with some better test data.